# filesystem.py is unable to be read even though the file exists and my user has all permissions for the file (sqlmap)

Tags: mysql, security, sql-injection, penetration-testing, sqlmap

I am currently trying to test the security of a website I have recently come to host on Apache Linux 2023. With this I am trying to conduct an SQLi test and am trying to use the tool SQLMAP to brute force it. However, even thought I have installed both Python and SQLMAP to the manual on my device, whenever I run the command:

```
 python C:\Users\"myname"\sqlmap-dev\sqlmap.py -u "http://"mywebsite/"
```

It gives me the error:

```
[11:59:17] [CRITICAL] unable to read file 'C:\\Users\\"myname\\sqlmap-dev\\plugins\\dbms\\mssqlserver\\filesystem.py'
```

I have confirmed that the file does indeed exist within "C:\Users\"myname\sqlmap-dev\plugins\dbms\mssqlserver\" and further have confirmed that my user has the correct permissions and should be able to read that file, does anyone know why it is giving back that error?

Further, when I try to open the filesystem.py from my files, I get the error:

'Unable to Open 'filesystem.py'
unable to read file 'c:\Users'myname'\sqlmap-dev\plugins\mssqlserver\filesystem.pu' (Unknown (FileSystemError): An unknown error occured. PLease consult the log for more details.)

Answer (score -1):

based on my experience, to fix it just go to the following folder sqlmap\plugins\generic then there is a filesystem.py file. Then copy the file to the sqlmap\plugins\dbms\mssqlserver directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).